# Linux CLI program to verify/control nVidia hardware RAID?

Tags: linux, raid, monitoring, hardware-raid, graphics-processing-unit

I have a server with a Supermicro motherboard that has an nVidia RAID controller on board.  When I boot up, I can hit F10 and see/modify the RAID settings.

However, I don't want to reboot this server in order to check the status of the RAID array.  Is there any kind of Linux/Ubuntu server CLI program that will let me do that?  Ideally, there be an equivalent of 3ware's `tw_cli` program.

When installing Ubuntu, it recognized the RAID array as a single drive.  I set it up without configuring software RAID.  On the other hand, the `lspci` command reports that I have 3 of the following (not one):

```
00:05.0 RAID bus controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP55 SATA Controller (rev a3) (prog-if 85)
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Device 1411
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0 (750ns min, 250ns max)
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 21
    Region 0: I/O ports at b480 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at b400 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at b080 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at b000 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at ac00 [size=16]
    Region 5: Memory at dbef9000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [cc] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed+
    Kernel driver in use: sata_nv
    Kernel modules: sata_nv
```

Furthermore the `dmraid -s` command returns:

```
*** Active Set
name   : nvidia_cdccgggj
size   : 1953525120
stride : 128
type   : mirror
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
```

Noticeably absent from the result of `dmraid` is my 3ware RAID card that is also in this server.

Comment: _WHAT_ nVidia RAID controller?

Comment: `sudo lspci` reports is as "NVIDIA Corporation MCP55" RAID.  Does that help?

Comment: That sounds like the usual NVIDIA fakeraid, not hardware RAID.

Comment: Hmmmm...ok.  Updated the question to include more data.  Is this the fakeraid?

Comment: `dmraid` manages fakeraid here, not 3ware hardware RAID. If you actually have a 3ware card in here, you'll have to use their tools to manage it.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes the tw_cli is a great tool for the 3Ware...was looking for the same thing for nVidia, but since its fakeraid, dmraid will do just fine.  I really thought the nvidia stuff was real RAID given that Ubuntu had no problems seeing it and installing on it.